# Как запустить проект в vscode с cmake и haunt

Tags: c++, c, cmake, mingw

перешел на vscode с clion и не могу понять как запустить и собрать проект
Вот сам проект, пытаюсь для начала собрать его через консоль стандартной командой:

`cmake ..`

Дает вот такую ошибку, и я смотрел похожие темы, но pat у меня к mingw прописан, и vs 2022 стоит...

```
C:\Users\dimma\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\cpp_server\_build>cmake ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/dimma/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/cpp_server/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/dimma/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/cpp_server/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

И как вообще делать сборку и запуск с помощью vscode?
Вот допустим конфигурация:

```
{
                "name": "win64",
              "type": "cppbuild",
              "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
              "command": "D:/Mingw64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
              "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"],
              "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
              },
              "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
              "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
              },
              "detail": "compiler: D:/Mingw64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"
            },
```

Но при попытке запустить через f5 или run win64 у меня просто выскакивает вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнительная информация:

```
C:\Users\dimma\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\cpp_server\_build>gcc --version
gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


C:\Users\dimma\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\cpp_server\_build>g++ --version
g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


C:\Users\dimma\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\cpp_server\_build>cmake --version
cmake version 3.23.0-rc2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Буду рад помощи

Comment: Вам же явно говорит - не нашло компилятора. То, что он установлен, ещё не значит, что его сможет найти.

Comment: @KoVadim что нужно сделать чтобы нашло?
Явно указать в cmake как-то?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275348/how-to-specify-new-gcc-path-for-cmake